# Like and dislike displaying at the same time error

Tags: php, jquery, laravel-5

After a lot of errors and headaches i acheive the like and dislike button (like the one on youtube) the concept is that i want the user to be able to like or dislike a style if he/she chooses but the problem is the user can like and dislike a style the same time.

**LIKE YOUTUBE LIKES & DISLIKES**

[image: youtube likes and dislikes]

**THE ERROR**

[image: the app like and dislike issue]

**MY CODE (JS) (like click function)**

```
styleLike = $("#c-style-like-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'");

styleLike.on("click", styleLike, function() {

    styleId = $("#style-id-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();
    styleIdAjax = $("#style-id-ajax-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();
    userId = $("#user-id").val();
    like = 1;
    likeCliked = $("#like-cliked-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val("1");
    dislikeCliked = $("#dislike-cliked-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val("0");

    // check if dislike is clicked after like...

    $.ajax({
        url: "catalogue@style@like@processing",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"like" : like, "user" : userId, "styleId" : styleIdAjax},
        headers: { "X-CSRF-Token" : $("meta[name=_token]").attr("content") },
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {

        styleId = $("#style-id-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();

        // swal("Liked", "Wow you really like this style.", "success");
        styleLikeButton = $("#style-like-" + styleId);
        styleLikeButton.detach();

        likeText = $("#c-style-like-" + styleId);

        console.log("dislikedType:" + response.likedType);

        if (response.likedType == "liked") {

            likeText.removeClass("footer-links");
            likeText.addClass("blue-liked-link");
            likeText.html(response.likedText);
            //console.log("likedType:" + response.likedType);
            //console.log("likedText:" + response.likedText);

        }

        if (response.likedType == "like"){

            likeText.removeClass("blue-liked-link");
            likeText.addClass("footer-links");
            likeText.html(response.likedText);
            //console.log("likedType:" + response.likedType);
            //console.log("likedText:" + response.likedText);

        }

        //likeText.removeClass("footer-links");
        //likeText.addClass("blue-liked-link");
        //likeText.html("<i class='. "'fa fa-heart'".'></i> Liked");

        likeLabel = $("#like-label-" + styleId);
        likeLabel.html(response.likeLabel);
    });

});
```

**MY CODE (JS) (dislike click function)**

```
styleDislike = $("#c-style-dislike-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'");

styleDislike.on("click", styleDislike, function() {

    styleId = $("#style-id-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();
    styleIdAjax = $("#style-id-ajax-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();
    userId = $("#user-id").val();
    dislike = 0;

    $.ajax({
        url: "catalogue@style@dislike@processing",
        type: "POST",
        data: {"dislike" : dislike, "user" : userId, "styleId" : styleIdAjax},
        headers: { "X-CSRF-Token" : $("meta[name=_token]").attr("content") },
        context: document.body
    }).done(function(response) {

        styleId = $("#style-id-'. $catalogueStyle->id.'").val();

        // swal("Liked", "Wow you really like this style.", "success");
        styleLikeButton = $("#style-like-" + styleId);
        styleLikeButton.detach();

        dislikeText = $("#c-style-dislike-" + styleId);

        console.log("likedType:" + response.dislikedType);

        if (response.dislikedType == "disliked") {

            dislikeText.removeClass("footer-links");
            dislikeText.addClass("blue-liked-link");
            dislikeText.html(response.dislikedText);
            //console.log("likedType:" + response.likedType);
            //console.log("likedText:" + response.likedText);

        }

        if (response.dislikedType == "dislike"){

            dislikeText.removeClass("blue-liked-link");
            dislikeText.addClass("footer-links");
            dislikeText.html(response.dislikedText);
            //console.log("likedType:" + response.likedType);
            //console.log("likedText:" + response.likedText);

        }

        //likeText.removeClass("footer-links");
        //likeText.addClass("blue-liked-link");
        //likeText.html("<i class='. "'fa fa-heart'".'></i> Liked");

        likeLabel = $("#like-label-" + styleId);
        likeLabel.html(response.dislikeLabel);
    });

});
```

**MY CONTROLLER (like)**

```
public function like(){

    $user = Input::get('user');
    $style = Input::get('styleId');

    $user = Crypt::decrypt($user);
    $style = Crypt::decrypt($style);
    $like = Input::get('like');


    $Stylelike = Cataloguestylelike::where("user_id",$user)->where("style_id",$style)->where("style_likes_count",1)->first();

    $Styledislike = Cataloguestylelike::where("user_id",$user)->where("style_id",$style)->where("style_likes_count",0)->first();


    if ( (count($Stylelike) == 0) ) {

        $styleLike = new Cataloguestylelike;
        $styleLike->user_id = $user;
        $styleLike->style_id = $style;
        $styleLike->style_likes_count = $like;
        $styleLike->save();

        $likedText = "<i class='fa fa-heart'></i> Liked";

        $likedType = "liked";

        $styleId = $style;

        $styleLikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 1)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleDislikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 0)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleLikesCount = count($styleLikes);

        $styleDislikesCount = count($styleDislikes);

        if ($styleLikesCount == 0) {

            $styleLikesCount = "No likes";

        }else{

            if ( $styleLikesCount == 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = $styleLikesCount . " " . "like";
            }

            if ( $styleLikesCount > 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleLikesCount) . " " . "likes";
            }
        }


        if ( $styleDislikesCount == 0) {

             $styleDislikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if (  $styleDislikesCount == 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount =  $styleDislikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if (  $styleDislikesCount > 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleDislikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }

        $response = array('likedType' => $likedType, 'likedText' => $likedText, 'likeLabel' => "like | (". $styleLikesCount .") & dislike | (". $styleDislikesCount .")");


        return response()->json($response);

    }else{

        if ( (count($Stylelike) >= 1) ){

        $styleLike = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 1)->where("style_id",$style)->where("user_id",$user)->first();

        $styleLike->delete();

        $likedText = "<i class='fa fa-heart'></i> Like";

        $likedType = "like";

        $styleId = $style;

        $styleLikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 1)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleDislikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 0)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleLikesCount = count($styleLikes);

        $styleDislikesCount = count($styleDislikes);

        if ($styleLikesCount == 0) {

            $styleLikesCount = "No likes";

        }else{

            if ( $styleLikesCount == 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = $styleLikesCount . " " . "like";
            }

            if ( $styleLikesCount > 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleLikesCount) . " " . "likes";
            }
        }


        if ( $styleDislikesCount == 0) {

             $styleDislikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if (  $styleDislikesCount == 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount =  $styleDislikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if (  $styleDislikesCount > 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleDislikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }

        $response = array('likedType' => $likedType, 'likedText' => $likedText, 'likeLabel' => "like | (". $styleLikesCount .") & dislike | (". $styleDislikesCount .")");


        return response()->json($response);

        }
    }

}
```

**MY CONTROLLER (dislike)**

```
public function dislike(){

    $user = Input::get('user');
    $style = Input::get('styleId');

    $user = Crypt::decrypt($user);
    $style = Crypt::decrypt($style);
    $dislike = Input::get('dislike');


    $Styledislike = Cataloguestylelike::where("user_id",$user)->where("style_id",$style)->where("style_likes_count",0)->first();

    $Stylelike = Cataloguestylelike::where("user_id",$user)->where("style_id",$style)->where("style_likes_count",1)->first();

    if ( (count($Styledislike) == 0) ) {

        $styleLike = new Cataloguestylelike;
        $styleLike->user_id = $user;
        $styleLike->style_id = $style;
        $styleLike->style_likes_count = $dislike;
        $styleLike->save();

        $dislikedText = "<i class='fa fa-heartbeat'></i> Disliked";

        $dislikedType = "disliked";

        $styleId = $style;

        $styleLikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 1)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleDislikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 0)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleLikesCount = count($styleLikes);

        $styleDislikesCount = count($styleDislikes);

        if ($styleLikesCount == 0) {

            $styleLikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if ( $styleLikesCount == 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = $styleLikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if ( $styleLikesCount > 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleLikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }


        if ( $styleDislikesCount == 0) {

             $styleDislikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if (  $styleDislikesCount == 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount =  $styleDislikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if (  $styleDislikesCount > 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleDislikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }

        $response = array('dislikedType' => $dislikedType, 'dislikedText' => $dislikedText, 'dislikeLabel' => "like | (". $styleLikesCount .") & dislike | (". $styleDislikesCount .")");


        return response()->json($response);

    }else{

        if ( (count($Styledislike) >= 1) ){

        $styleLike = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 0)->where("style_id",$style)->where("user_id",$user)->first();

        $styleLike->delete();

        $dislikedText = "<i class='fa fa-heartbeat'></i> Dislike";

        $dislikedType = "dislike";

        $styleId = $style;

        $styleLikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 1)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleDislikes = Cataloguestylelike::where('style_likes_count','=', 0)->where("style_id",$style)->get();

        $styleLikesCount = count($styleLikes);

        $styleDislikesCount = count($styleDislikes);

        if ($styleLikesCount == 0) {

            $styleLikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if ( $styleLikesCount == 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = $styleLikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if ( $styleLikesCount > 1 ) {

                $styleLikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleLikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }


        if ( $styleDislikesCount == 0) {

             $styleDislikesCount = "No dislikes";

        }else{

            if (  $styleDislikesCount == 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount =  $styleDislikesCount . " " . "dislike";
            }

            if (  $styleDislikesCount > 1 ) {

                 $styleDislikesCount = wasamarKCount($styleDislikesCount) . " " . "dislikes";
            }
        }

        $response = array('dislikedType' => $dislikedType, 'dislikedText' => $dislikedText, 'dislikeLabel' => "like | (". $styleLikesCount .") & dislike | (". $styleDislikesCount .")");


        return response()->json($response);

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to describe the behaviour you want to applied here, if the user like accidentally then he/she want to dislike or the opposite, is that possible, and how you manage this, in _server-side_ not the _client-side_?

Comment: You need to provide the [mcve] code, remove the non-applicable code. It is up to you to debug the problem down to the minimal code that produces the problem.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki this concept, if the user likes (liked) a style he can choose to unlike it (like), but if the user dislikes (disliked) a style he can to reset it back that is (dislike) but paraventure he likes and clicks the dislike link the same time or the reverse it should disable the previous click and enable the current click so also in the controllers.